# I want to disable Lua obfuscation

Tags: lua, obfuscation, deobfuscation

This is Lua from some game.
I would like to modify and use this.
But it's obfuscated.

Here's the structure I figured out:

For example, entering a chat calls the following Lua file.

`return function (self,type,message)  _G["\u{5F}\u{49}\u{06B}\u{49}\u{6B}\u{6B}\u{6C}\u{06B}\u{49}\u{069}\u{6B}\u{69}\u{006C}\u{6C}\u{049}\u{0069}\u{06C}\u{6C}\u{006B}\u{69}\u{6C}\u{06B}\u{06C}\u{49}\u{6B}\u{0069}\u{06C}\u{0069}\u{49}\u{006B}\u{0069}\u{6C}\u{69}"]["\u{049}\u{0069}\u{6B}\u{69}\u{049}\u{6B}\u{049}\u{006C}\u{69}\u{6B}\u{006C}\u{69}\u{06C}\u{6B}\u{6B}\u{69}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{0069}\u{06B}\u{6B}\u{6B}\u{006C}\u{69}\u{6C}\u{06C}\u{49}\u{006C}\u{049}\u{49}\u{49}\u{6C}"][(530247052)-(442715560)+(417474590)](self,type,message) end`

The code calls an unknown global variable.
I also found a file with many unreadable global variables defined.

First, I performed the following calculation (530247052)-(442715560)+(417474590).
The result is 505006082

There was a similar pattern in the "chunk.lua" file where global variables were defined.
Here are some of them:

`[(1437643653)+(1949875078)-(2882512649)]=function(__a0,__a1,__a2)local ikiikkiKKk=223266510;ikiikkiKKk+=1811079080;(function(_iI0l1liIioIl,_o01ilio0oI00,_io0l1lioiIo1)local _1o0iIi1o1lo1=_iI0l1liIioIl[_G["\u{5F}\u{6C}\u{6B}\u{6B}\u{049}\u{006C}\u{49}\u{06B}\u{6B}\u{049}\u{06B}\u{49}\u{69}\u{0069}\u{006B}\u{6B}\u{049}\u{0049}\u{6C}\u{6B}\u{49}\u{49}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{69}\u{69}\u{049}\u{0049}\u{049}\u{06C}\u{0069}\u{069}\u{6C}"]["\u{69}\u{06C}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{069}\u{006C}\u{49}\u{69}\u{6B}\u{0049}\u{69}\u{06B}\u{0049}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{69}\u{69}\u{49}\u{006B}\u{006B}\u{06C}\u{006B}\u{69}\u{069}\u{0049}\u{06B}\u{069}\u{049}\u{06B}\u{0049}\u{69}\u{049}"][(1155173479)+(1577632519)-(1688057523)]][_G[_G["\u{05F}\u{0049}\u{6C}\u{69}\u{06B}\u{49}\u{49}\u{6C}\u{006C}\u{69}\u{6B}\u{49}\u{6B}\u{6C}\u{006B}\u{0049}\u{69}\u{69}\u{49}\u{6C}\u{0069}\u{69}\u{06C}\u{6C}\u{06B}\u{049}\u{69}\u{006C}\u{6C}\u{0049}\u{49}\u{006C}\u{0069}"]["\u{06C}\u{006C}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{006B}\u{0069}\u{49}\u{49}\u{6C}\u{69}\u{6C}\u{0049}\u{49}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{69}\u{0069}\u{49}\u{0069}\u{6C}\u{6B}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{49}\u{0049}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{6B}\u{06B}\u{69}"][(1334598761)+(865866175)-(2122149422)]][_G["\u{005F}\u{006C}\u{006B}\u{06B}\u{49}\u{6C}\u{49}\u{006B}\u{6B}\u{49}\u{6B}\u{49}\u{069}\u{0069}\u{6B}\u{6B}\u{49}\u{0049}\u{6C}\u{6B}\u{0049}\u{49}\u{06C}\u{006C}\u{0069}\u{0069}\u{049}\u{49}\u{49}\u{6C}\u{69}\u{69}\u{06C}"]["\u{69}\u{6C}\u{006C}\u{06C}\u{0069}\u{6C}\u{49}\u{0069}\u{6B}\u{49}\u{69}\u{06B}\u{49}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{69}\u{69}\u{49}\u{06B}\u{006B}\u{006C}\u{06B}\u{69}\u{69}\u{49}\u{6B}\u{0069}\u{49}\u{6B}\u{0049}\u{069}\u{49}"][(475540248)+(1474562382)-(1625698704)]]]local _1oiI0I1o1l0i={}for _1l0IoI1l1ioi=1,10000 do _1oiI0I1o1l0i[_1l0IoI1l1ioi]=_G["\u{5F}\u{06C}\u{06B}\u{006B}\u{049}\u{6C}\u{49}\u{006B}\u{6B}\u{049}\u{06B}\u{0049}\u{069}\u{069}\u{06B}\u{006B}\u{49}\u{49}\u{6C}\u{6B}\u{049}\u{49}\u{6C}\u{6C}\u{69}\u{0069}\u{49}\u{49}\u{0049}\u{006C}\u{0069}\u{69}\u{6C}"]["\u{69}\u{6C}\u{06C}\u{6C}\u{69}\u{6C}\u{49}\u{0069}\u{06B}\u{49}\u{069}\u{006B}\u{0049}\u{006C}\u{06C}\u{0069}\u{0069}\u{049}\u{6B}\u{6B}\u{6C}\u{006B}\u{69}\u{0069}\u{49}\u{6B}\u{069}\u{49}\u{06B}\u{49}\u{069}\u{49}"][(460084513)+(758444488)-(-873305452)]end`

(1437643653)+(1949875078)-(2882512649) A function is defined in a global variable.
The reason I imported this part is because the result of (1437643653)+(1949875078)-(2882512649) is the same as the result "505006082" calculated in the file above.
And it has the same three parameters.

But I don't know how to proceed from here.

What should I try next?
and Is what I'm currently trying getting closer to the answer?

Everything is described above.
I need a tool or someone who knows how to solve this.

Comment: _"But I don't know how to proceed from here."_ - You proceed by _not stopping_. Try doing 1 line at a time - but keep on at it and eventually it'll add-up and a more complete picture of the program will reveal itself.

Comment: @Dai I try to proceed to the next line, but I don't know what it means. :(

Comment: I might suggest that you first attempt to only complete the hex-decode step - otherwise you'll keep on running into identifiers you haven't seen before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These `\u{xxx}` are UTF-8 encoded characters, you can just print them using lua to get its original value, e.g.

```
print("\u{5F}\u{49}\u{06B}\u{49}\u{6B}\u{6B}\u{6C}\u{06B}\u{49}\u{069}\u{6B}\u{69}\u{006C}\u{6C}\u{049}\u{0069}\u{06C}\u{6C}\u{006B}\u{69}\u{6C}\u{06B}\u{06C}\u{49}\u{6B}\u{0069}\u{06C}\u{0069}\u{49}\u{006B}\u{0069}\u{6C}\u{69}")
```

You will get `_IkIkklkIikillIillkilklIkiliIkili`. Keep converting all these similar strings, e.g. the first function can be deobfuscated to:

```
return function (self,type,message)
    _G["_IkIkklkIikillIillkilklIkiliIkili"]["IikiIkIliklilkkillikkklillIlIIIl"][505006082](self,type,message)
end
```

Obviously these keys and variable names are also obfuscated. You can further replace them with short names, it should be easier to search for relevant information in the code.

Comment: I tried this.
However, in the code, Unicode {06B} and {6B} both point to the same string, so I wonder if this is the right step. And even if you convert it to a string, you still don't know what it means.

Comment: They are the same. And this is just the first step, you need to process all the code, then gradually replace the obfuscated parts with the known ones.

Comment: For example you may get `_G["_IoioIooIOOIo"] = print` finally, then you know that `_IoioIooIOOIo` maps to `print`. But this will be a tedium process.